# How to plot result of table function using ggplot barplot (problem with x axis values)

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a data frame and I used the table function to find the ratio of the variable "surrounded" and "issuance". Here is the code I wrote:

```
out <- table( df_select$Insured_Age_Group,df_select$Policy_Status)
out <- cbind(out, ratio = out[,2]/rowSums(out))
```

the result of this code is shown below:

```
  Issuance Surrended     ratio
1    31046      5735 0.1559229
2    20039      4409 0.1803420
3    20399      9228 0.3114726
4    48677     17216 0.2612721
5    30045      8132 0.2130078
6    13947      4106 0.2274414
7     3157      1047 0.2490485
```

if you need a code to generate this data frame:

```
structure(c(31046, 20039, 20399, 48677, 30045, 13947, 3157, 5735, 
4409, 9228, 17216, 8132, 4106, 1047, 0.155922894972948, 0.18034195026178, 
0.311472643197084, 0.261272062282792, 0.213007831940697, 0.227441422478258, 
0.249048525214082), .Dim = c(7L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"), c("Issuance", "Surrended", "ratio"
)))
```

Now I want to plot these ratios for each group. I am wondering how I should pass x numbers to ggplot? Basically, here my x is (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) which are 7 age group. Should I pass it manually to ggplot? Something like the one I showed below? or there is a better way to do it?

```
ggplot(data=out, aes(x=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), y=ratio)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) +
  theme(legend.position = "right")+
  xlab("")+
  geom_text(aes(label=Total), vjust=-0.5 , hjust=0.7, color="black", position = position_dodge(0.9),size=3)
```

but this returns `Error:` data `must be a data frame, or other object coercible by fortify(), not a numeric vector` error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`out` is a matrix, convert it to dataframe. It is better to create new column that you want to plot in the data itself. Not sure what `Total` is but for labels I am using `ratio` column.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data.frame(out) %>%
  mutate(x = row_number()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, ratio)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) +
  theme(legend.position = "right")+
  xlab("")+
  geom_text(aes(label=round(ratio, 2)), vjust=-0.5 , hjust=0.7, color="black", position = position_dodge(0.9),size=3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Ronak Shah for the clear answer. So in this case, numbers were in order and that's why II guess you used x=row_number(). What if x were numbers like 7,60,80,90,200? Then you had to manually add these as a new column to `out` dataframe before plotting?

Comment: If you want `x` in increasing order you can first `arrange` the data and then use `row_number()` i.e `data.frame(out) %>% arrange(col_name) %>% mutate(x = row_number())`